# Scrape specific DOM Node and children from string, insert into new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, web-scraping

I need to pull a specific DOM node and children from one page, and insert it into another. I have gotten close to this, however it only seems to grab the containing element, not the children as needed:

```
  fetch('/sameorigin/page', {})
    .then(function(res){
      return res.text();
    })
    .then(function(res){
      var html = res;
      console.log($(html).find('#chart')[0], 'chart');

      var chartOne = $(html).find('#chart')[0];

      $('#chartOne').append( chartOne );
    })
```

This simply gives me an empty `<div id="chart></div>` with none of the children. I have tried both `$(html).find` and `$(html).children(), both give the same result of an empty div

How can i get that div along with all of its children and insert it into the current page at `#chartOne`?

Comment: What does the `console.log` output show?

Comment: sounds like the page youre fetching is rendering the chart's children with javascript, which means just grabbing the source won't work since javascript doesnt execute on a regular scrape.  You might need phantom or something.

Comment: Yes, you're right @Rooster Any way to do this client side?